# How to activate a class during a specific moment?

Tags: actionscript-3

Let's say I have a spinning class that spins in the enter frame. And I have a main class with a start button, the object is already added to stage, so it spins before pressing the start button.

Is there a way to activate an object class only after pressing the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You give your spinner a property `public var active:Boolean=false;` and when you need, you switch that to true. And in enter frame listener you query `if (!active) return;` so that your spinner won't spin while `active` is false.